# Does Evernote Use HTTP to Make Calls to its API?

Tags: http, oauth, evernote

I am creating a client program that calls various APIs, one of which is the Evernote API, through purely HTTP calls, without the use of any SDKs provided by Evernote.  I realize that this makes my life harder, but it makes the lives of the users of my product much easier.

So far I have been able to authenticate with oauth 1.0 to the Evernote server.  However, it's not immediately clear how to make the HTTP call after I have the oauth_token.

Where is the endpoint to make API calls to create a note on an oauth-authenticated Evernote user account?  What are the url parameters for such a call?  Or, what are the requirements to include in such an HTTP request?
Does Evernote use HTTP to make such calls anyway?  If not, what do they use?
Do I have to format the note in XML format, or does it accept JSON as well?

Comment: *"but it makes the lives of the users of my product much easier"* - can you elaborate on how it makes things easier for the end user as opposed to using the SDK/APIs?

Comment: Well if you’re dead set on re-doing work again that’s already been done … then you might go look through the source code of one of their SDKs – they’re all up on GitHub for you to browse freely – to go and figure out what endpoints they are calling and how … have fun.

Comment: @ScottMcGready My users are non-coders ideally and they would access my application through an endpoint that would post notes for them from another location.

Comment: @CBroe tell me something I don't know.  Haha.  I really was just looking for someone who already had some experience with this sort of thing, or someone who had already looked into the source code.  I'm not unwilling to look into the source code of course, I'm just trying to be efficient about it before I waste my time looking.

Comment: I think you should go back and have a good read of the api. You could run it exactly as you described using custom scripts that check a mailbox periodically.

Answer (score 1):

Evernote does not have a RESTful API. According to the CTO, it's due to a requirement to shuttle very large amounts of data and HTTP is not efficient. There is a project on github aiming to implement a RESTful API for Evernote.

https://github.com/ttddyy/evernote-rest-webapp

CTO's Reasoning:
http://blog.programmableweb.com/2013/10/03/is-evernotes-restless-api-approach-a-model-for-other-api-designs/

I haven't used Evernote in years and never used the API.

Comment: Yeah, I read those.  Interesting article overall.  However, they don't mention what exactly they use in order to send these messages, granted they do at least say that they REST is not used.  Does anyone know what protocol they do use to connect?  Perhaps I can add in that protocol to my application.

Answer (score 1):

Evernote uses [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) which can be a bit tricky to deal with. This choice is explained in [this blog post](https://blog.evernote.com/tech/2011/05/26/evernote-and-thrift/). I really advise you to use the SDK as it hides all the thrift complexity.
As mentioned above, a rest wrapper is available on github. It seems very cool but it's new and not official. Use it at your own risk.